# ImageView resize dynamically acccording to the image size in android

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

How can I resize ImageView dynamically according to the height and width of an image in android ?

Comment: It does, automagically

Comment: use property `"wrap_content"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in your ImageView. You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds).

ThereFore, your imageview xml will be something like:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image"" />
```

Answer (score 0):

ImageView have property `wrap_content`

via XML

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/your_image"" />
```

via JAVA code

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);
```